# Loading extra services in Symfony 2 during the boot process (of container)

Tags: symfony

I'm getting this error message:

```
[22-Oct-2012 06:03:24] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\FileLoader::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder, instance of pluginsProdProjectContainer given, called in ....
```

On the specific line it reads like this:

```
$loader = new XMLFileLoader($container, new FileLocator($config_path));
```

This seems to be the result of SF2 automatically generates and loads a cache file which is: pluginsProdProjectContainer.php that seems to extains the container:

```
class pluginsProdProjectContainer extends Container
```

For that reason, when I pass the container into the XMLFileLoader, instance of Container is passed instead of ContainerBuilder. I'm not quite sure how to get around this?

Comment: What is $container in your example - how you build/get this object? Is it in class extending Extension?

Comment: You are right, I think I should do this within the extension. I was getting the container from the $kernel right after boot() which seems to always return that cache class.

Comment: Your problem is probably that you are trying use Container object but your XMLFileLoader expects ContainerBuilder object as the first argument

Comment: You are absolutely right, I now switched to do it inside the DI Pass so that I can access the ContainerBuilder. Wonder how I can accept your comment as answer.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer. Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably that you are trying use `Container` object but your `XMLFileLoader` expects `ContainerBuilder` object as the first argument